# Google Calendar does not sync the remote calendar added via webcal:// url (anymore)

Tags: google-calendar, synchronization

On my website I offer a Google Subscription Link like `https://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=<target>` so my guests can import my Events in their Google Calendar.
The target is a webcal-Link which provides an always-up-to-date ics-file.

It works just fine: if someone clicks the link, google opens up and adds the calendar as it should do.

BUT Google Calendar does not stay in sync with my source (anymore). On Googles support center they say subscribed calendars will be synced within 12h. Now there are 4 days gone and the calendar ist still not in sync. I had used this Link for years and suddenly there is no sync anymore.

Then I imported the plain webcal-Link in iOS Calender just to be sure. And (as expected) there it just works fine. If I add new Events, they are displayed within a hour on my iPhone. So there shouldn't be a problem with the source.

Does anyone encountered the same issue with Google Calendar sync and has found a solution for this issue?

I am happy about any help :)

---

EDIT: I suspect it's maybe an issue with the cache headers. But I can't see any issue there:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.13.8
Date: Tue, 27 Aug 2019 10:48:52 GMT
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 90671
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store, public, s-maxage=3600
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
ETag: "14090e1096c521d1a716e4519d81da6f"
```

Am I wrong?

Comment: Did you eventually see a sync?

Running into a similar problem. My suspicion is that Google is phasing out refreshing http ical sources in favour of people implementing on their Google Calendar API. It's a real pain too because other email clients do this _just fine_